# Can I use 1M Libor monthly data to estimate Vasicek parameters and use them to price quarterly swap

Tags: vasicek

I am working on CVA algorithm.  I am using vasicek model to evolve short rate.  At hand, I am supposed to value a fixed to floating IRS quarterly paying.

Can I use 1M Libor as surrogate for short rate and estimate the parameters of vasicek and then calibrate the market price of risk using current zero rates?. IF I used 1M Libor, what time increment should I give to evolve shortrate (Euler's discretization) for three month points in evaluating the quarterly swap?